# Angular / Firestore - 'Where' query returning error 'property does not exist on type AngularFirestoreCollection'

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get a specific document from a firestore collection based upon an URL parameter that is passed into the argument, but as I've initialized the collection using `expensesCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Expense>`, the `where` query is returning the following error:

> *TS2339: Property 'where' does not exist on type 'AngularFirestoreCollection*

The 'ViewExpense' component is accessed after clicking on a datatable row on the 'ExpensesList' component, which passes the expense ID as a parameter, which is used in the where query.

-

**expense-list.component.html:**

```
<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: tableColumns" routerLink="/expenses/view/{{row.expenseId}}"></mat-row>
```

-

**view-expense.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';

import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection } from 'angularfire2/firestore';

import { Expense } from '../expenseModel';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-view-expense',
  templateUrl: './view-expense.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./view-expense.component.scss']
})

export class ViewExpenseComponent implements OnInit {

  expenseId: any;

  expensesCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Expense>;
  expenses: Observable<Expense[]>;

  expense: Observable<Expense>;

  constructor(private db: AngularFirestore, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
        console.log(params);
        this.expenseId = params.expenseId;
    })

    this.expensesCollection = this.db.collection('/expenses');

    this.expenses = this.expensesCollection.snapshotChanges().map(changes = {
      return changes.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Expense;
        data.id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return data;
      })
    })
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getExpense();
  }

  getExpense() {
    /* ---- ERROR HERE ---- */
    this.expense = this.expensesCollection.where('expenseId', '==', this.expenseId);
    console.log('this.expense: ' + this.expense);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 61):

There's no `where` function in `AngularFirestoreCollection`, instead you should supply the where condition in the second argument of `collection()`, like this:

```
this.expensesCollection = this.db.collection('/expenses', ref => ref.where('expenseId', '==', this.expenseId));
```

Reference: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/querying-collections.md

Outdated / outright wrong documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries

Comment: @mikegross The documentation you linked is correct. This is a difference between the AngularFirestore NPM module you are using and the vanilla Firebase JS SDK

Comment: What if I want to have multiple queries?

Comment: `queryDoc=this.collection("Assessment",ref=>ref.where("community.community_id","==",communityId).orderBy('assessment_index', sortOrder).startAfter(lastDocRef).limit(_limit));` you can do like this by concat where.